# How to return last day of month in ngx-bootstrap datepicker angular

Tags: html, angular, forms, ngx-bootstrap, angular12

[image]

Below is my code where I need to display calendar with month and year and when user selects month and year it should display last day of that month with year. I am able to get the date as 01 June 2022 using below code, where as I need date as 30 June 2022

Comment: Please not post code snippets as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is using a library like `moment` (depreacated) or `dayjs`. Take the date you get from datepicker, and use it with the library to get the end date of the month-year.

Change the `dateInputFormat` to `YYYY-MM-DDDD` in the `bsConfig`.

Inside your `getDate()` function process the datePicker date to get proper format.

Example code:

```
const date = '2022-06-01';
console.log('Print date: ', moment(date).endOf('month').format('DD MM YYYY'));
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: How can I display only current year and month from march to till current month in bsDatepicker?